# Terraform apply being run twice in gitlab CI - how to prevent?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

We have a pipeline that includes "terraform plan" and "terraform apply" as separate CI steps, so that in production we can manually review changes before applying (however in review apps / staging we're happy for them to run automatically). The plan is passed as an artifact between the jobs.

We've had a couple of issues where developers have re-run the "terraform apply" job without re-running "terraform plan". I'm trying to work out how to identify this and prevent it.

I'm surprised that the terraform plan doesn't e.g. include a hash of the terraform state, and so apply could identify that the state has changed and refuse to continue.

Is there a suggested way to fix this? We've tried:

- Searching for options in terraform to avoid this (nothing so far)
- Searching for options in gitlab to avoid this (nothing so far)

We're currently looking into taking our own checksum of the tfstate file in the plan stage, and then checking that at the start of the apply stage - but I can't help feeling this ought to be out there already.

(State is stored in an S3 bucket. We also use dynamodb for locking)

Cut down .gitlab-ci.yml for illustration:

```yaml
stages:
  - plan
  - apply

terraform plan:
   image: hashicorp/terraform:0.12.26
   stage: plan
   script:
      - terraform init 
      - terraform plan -out terraform.plan
   artifacts:
     paths:
        - terraform.plan

terraform apply:
   image: hashicorp/terraform:0.12.26
   stage: apply
   script:
      - terraform apply -auto-approve terraform.plan
   rules:
      - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
        when: manual
      - when: on_success
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file please?

Comment: Hmmm... that's odd. The apply does check that the state matches what the plan saw and should error if anything has changed in between so it shouldn't be possible to make changes with an apply based on a plan and then apply again without refreshing the plan if things have changed in between (IIRC a no-op apply will complete okay anyway so a double tap of the apply being idempotent should be fine). Can you work out a [mcve] that reproduces this at all?

Comment: I'll try to find something - difficult without needing real credentials etc.